# Learning rate change by user while training

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

Hi I want to be able to change the learning rate manually while the model is training. Is there any possible way to do something like that?

Comment: Which library are you using? Setting the learning rate manually might not be the best choice, I think it's better if you look into one of the strategies such as the various LR decary strategies or cycling rates. If you still want to do that, you can always just use a config file an load it each epoch or batch. On another subject, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks!
I meant that I want to update my learning rate without inputting the learning rate ahead (config file as you suggested), but while the learning process goes on.